# Redirecting Events to handlers inside custom controls

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have mad a custom control. and i need to redirect the Event handler. i have cut the code down dramatically to try and articulate what im trying to do.

```
public class RemoteDesktop : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public event OnConnectingEventHandler OnConnecting;
    public delegate void OnConnectingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs Arguments);

    public event OnDisconnectingEventHandler OnDisconnecting;
    public delegate void OnDisconnectingEventHandler(Object sender, IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent Arguments);

    private AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting RDPUserControl = new AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting();
    public RemoteDesktop()
    {
        this.RDPUserControl.BeginInit();
        this.RDPUserControl.SuspendLayout();
        base.Child = RDPUserControl;
        this.RDPUserControl.ResumeLayout();
        this.RDPUserControl.EndInit();
    }
}
public class RemoteDesktopViewModel
{
    public RemoteDesktopViewModel()
    {
        RemoteDesktop newRDC = new RemoteDesktop();
        newRDC.OnConnecting += new RemoteDesktop.OnConnectingEventHandler(newRDC_OnConnecting);
    }

    void newRDC_OnConnecting(object sender, EventArgs Arguments)
    {
        //DoStuff
    }
}
```

basically it all works, i can connect and disconnect to the remote computer however i cannot get the fired events to occur in my view model.

Can anyone help me figure out how i can point my events correctly.
Thank you.

Thanks to some help i have the resolution
Step 1:
Declare delegates outside the class (within the namespace)
Step 2:
Declare the events to be called for the control.
Step 3: use the event handlers of the controls to reise the delegates you created

Completed Code

```
 public delegate void OnConnectingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs Arguments);
 public delegate void OnDisconnectingEventHandler(Object sender,IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent Arguments);

public class RemoteDesktop : WindowsFormsHost
{
    public event OnConnectingEventHandler IsConnecting;
    public event OnDisconnectingEventHandler IsDisconnecting;

    private AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting RDPUserControl = new AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting();
    public RemoteDesktop()
    {
        this.RDPUserControl.BeginInit();
        this.RDPUserControl.SuspendLayout();
        base.Child = RDPUserControl;
        this.RDPUserControl.ResumeLayout();
        this.RDPUserControl.EndInit();

        RDPUserControl.OnConnecting += RemoteDesktop_OnConnecting;
        RDPUserControl.OnDisconnected += RDPUserControl_OnDisconnected;
    }
    void RDPUserControl_OnDisconnected(object sender, IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent e)
    {
        IsDisconnecting(sender, e);
    }

    void RemoteDesktop_OnConnecting(object sender, EventArgs Arguments)
    {
        IsConnecting(sender, Arguments);
    }
}
public class RemoteDesktopViewModel
{
    public RemoteDesktopViewModel()
    {
        RemoteDesktop newRDC = new RemoteDesktop();
        newRDC.IsConnecting += new RemoteDesktop.OnConnectingEventHandler(newRDC_OnConnecting);
    }

    void newRDC_OnConnecting(object sender, EventArgs Arguments)
    {
        //DoStuff
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that raises the `OnConnecting` event. From what we can see the event is never raised so that would explain why the view model handler is never called.

Comment: RDPUserControl.OnConnecting += RemoteDesktop_OnConnecting; the activeX control raises the event when connecting.

Comment: So where's the code that shows when the ActiveX control connects? I assume it doesn't happen in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
//at the constractor of the class
OnConnecting+=RDC_OnConnecting;
```

then you can write your logic in method:newRDC_OnConnecting. make sure OnConnectingEventHandler have same method signatures with newRDC_OnConnecting.